# Cant find Visual Studio Installer Projects on Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

After finishing my C# application I had to make an installer. After seeing that the default installer projects are gone, i searched for a replacement.

I found the Visual Studio Installer Projects. I downloaded the file from here: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d.

When i restarted Visual Studio, opened my project, clicked "add new project" and here is what I got: [image]

Problem is that I cant find the setup project. I have tried repairing the install. I restarted Visual Studio several times.

### My Question:

How can I find the installer project and why it's not working for me.

If I cant make it work, are there any alternatives ? (except InstallShield)

### Additional info:

Visual Studio 2013 Community with update 4

Windows 8.1 64-bit

Comment: Did you try completely removing at and reinstalling instead of just repairing?

Comment: I did both. Uninstalled then installed back. Still nothing.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 does not support  installer project any more
you mus use installed  or Wix.
try searching Nuget or Visual Studio addons

Comment: I am trying to install the Microsoft Visual Studio Installer Projects extension. But the problem is that the extension installs, but no project is shown.

Comment: an alternative, which doesn't answer your question but might solve your problem, is to use WiX (also free, more flexible, but also more complex.)

Comment: Can you make your suggestion as an answer ? In my question I have said that I am looking for a replacement if this doesn't work.

Comment: @TomerKlein - Not true, MS released an extension to allow VS2013 to support installer projects.  It's not 100% perfect, but it works for a lot of scenarios.

Answer (score 12):

You could try `Tools > Extensions and Updates` and search for it:

[image]

Comment: Downloaded the file. Re-installed and still nothing.

Comment: Click the _More Information_ link, you're not the only one with problems.

Comment: In the _More_ _information_ link I saw that people are having this problem, but no solution has been given.

Comment: @user220258 I think your best bet is to choose an alternative like: WiX, InstallShield or Advanced Installer then.

Comment: InstallShield LE has corrected some problems it had but it is still cutting some features to the commercial version. It has some other limitations which I don't know if they are solved in the commercial version.
WiX may be complicated but a little bird told me that even in Microsoft they use it.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio setup projects no longer ship with Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/buckh/2011/03/17/visual-studio-setup-projects-vdproj-will-not-ship-with-future-versions-of-vs/)

However, you can download them [here.](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

Or use a third party library like WiX.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turns out that visual studio removed the support for installer projects in 2010.
but still you can download and install it in your version

[VS2013](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=UnniRavindranathan-MSFT.MicrosoftVisualStudio2013InstallerProjects)

[VS2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2015InstallerProjects)

[VS2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioClient.MicrosoftVisualStudio2017InstallerProjects)